# gnu makefile: if condition inside multirow assignment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to have **if** condition *inside* **multiple-rows assignment** of a variable?

The following code triggers an error:

```
MY_FILES=                      \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_1      \
ifeq ($(USE_ALTERNATIVE),1)    \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2a     \
else                           \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2b     \
endif                          \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_3      \
```

Result:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
make: *** [target] Error 2
```

But the following code also triggers an error:

```
MY_FILES=                      \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_1      \
ifeq ($(USE_ALTERNATIVE),1)
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2a     \
else
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2b     \
endif
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_3      \
```

Result:

```
Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
"make" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

If not possible, are there other simple alternatives to achieve this? The use case is a long list of include folders, which can have differences from place to place in function of some defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this too complicated.

```
MY_FILES :=  Path/To/IncludeFolder_1
ifeq ($(USE_ALTERNATIVE),1)
 MY_FILES += Path/To/IncludeFolder_2a
else                           
 MY_FILES += Path/To/IncludeFolder_2b
endif
MY_FILES += Path/To/IncludeFolder_3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a string-comparison function with relative ease yourself, so that you can facilitate the `$(if )` builtin function:

```
###### $(call str-eq,_string1_,_string2_)
## Compare two strings on equality. Strings are allowed to have blanks.
## Return non-empty if string $1 and $2 are identical, empty string otherwise.
## - `$(call str-eq,yes,no)` --> ` ` (empty string)
## - `$(call str-eq,yes ,yes)` --> ` ` (empty string)
## - `$(call str-eq,yes ,yes )`  --> `t`
str-eq = $(if $(subst x$1,,x$2),,t)

MY_FILES=                      \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_1      \
$(if $(call str-eq,$(USE_ALTERNATIVE),1)    \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2a,     \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_2b     \
 )                          \
  Path/To/IncludeFolder_3
```

The `str-eq` and many more utility functions can be found at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt.